# Applying condition in jQuery

Tags: jquery

So, I have following jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    jQuery.ias().on('rendered', function(items) {       
        first_function();
        second_function();              
    }); 
});
```

In this current setup, the functions are only fired when `jquery.ias()` is rendered.

How do I change the condition so that these functions are fired both when page is loaded AND when jQuery.ias is rendered?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

So, I actually have lots of functions that needs to be fired under the conditions mentioned above. Sorry for confusion

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    jQuery.ias().on('rendered', function(items) {       

    //1st function
    jQuery('#rh_post_add_done').click(function(){
      jQuery('#rh_post_add_done_click').click();
    }); 
    //2nd function
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery(".rh_setting_button").click(function(){
         var post_id_edit = jQuery(this).data("post_id");
             jQuery('#rh_' + post_id_edit).popup();
        });   
     })
     //3st function  
     //4th function
     //5th function
     //6th function
     //7th function, you get the point                  
    }); 
 });
```

Comment: your question is slightly misleading, do you mean when page is loaded OR when jQuery.ias is rendered?

Comment: Well, I have functions that need to be fired under both scenarios (when page is loaded AND when jQuery.ias is rendered. So, when the page is first loaded as well as when jQuery.ias is rendered. I can simply have functions outside of `jQuery.ias`, however, I have more than 10 functions and I really don't want to have doubles.

Comment: First of all, there is no sense to add `jQuery(document).ready` inside `jQuery(document).ready`

Comment: yeah. i was just copying and pasting for the sake of questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    jQuery.ias().on('rendered', function(items) {       
        first_function();
        second_function();              
    }); 

    first_function();
    second_function();  
});
```

Comment: I added an edit version. I actually have many functions and I really don't want to repeat the same thing outside of "rendered" portion.

Answer (score 1):

use following statement.So functions will call on both condition.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
            first_function();
            second_function(); 
        jQuery.ias().on('rendered', function(items) {       
            first_function();
            second_function();              
        }); 
    });
```

Comment: I added an edit version. I actually have many functions and I really don't want to repeat the same thing outside of "rendered" portion.